# Android layout editor dont show any thing?

Tags: android, layout, graphical-layout-editor

I download this layout from internet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView android:id="@id/left" android:background="@color/lightbackground" android:layout_width="10.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignTop="@id/header" android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bottom" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <TextView android:id="@id/right" android:background="@color/lightbackground" android:layout_width="10.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignTop="@id/header" android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bottom" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@id/header" android:background="@color/gray_review_header" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left">
        <TextView android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#ff111111" android:ellipsize="marquee" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@id/name" android:paddingLeft="5.0dip" android:paddingRight="5.0dip" android:fadingEdge="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" />
        <TextView android:textSize="12.0dip" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#ff666666" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@id/date" android:paddingRight="5.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
        <TextView android:textSize="14.0dip" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/black" android:id="@id/likes" android:paddingRight="5.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:singleLine="true" />
        <RatingBar android:id="@id/rate" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip" android:max="5" android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratebar_theme" android:numStars="5" android:stepSize="0.1" android:isIndicator="true" style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:textColor="#ff111111" android:id="@id/body" android:paddingLeft="5.0dip" android:paddingTop="2.0dip" android:paddingRight="5.0dip" android:paddingBottom="5.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left" android:layout_below="@id/header" />
    <TextView android:id="@id/bottom" android:background="@color/lightbackground" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10.0dip" android:layout_below="@id/body" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I add that layout to my layout folder of project.There is no error in above code,but when I open it with `layout editor`,there is no thing in `Graphical layout` tab.Do you know why this occures?

Comment: remove lines in your xml one by one to see which one make it fail (I expect it's the RatingBar)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your `layout.xml` file and Click on `Openwith` and select `Android Common Xml Editor`

try like this

Answer (score 0):

because there are lots of errors.

- id of a component is defined as,

  `android:id="@+id/left"`

but you have `defined` it as,

`android:id="@id/left"`

- Also it gives error in line `android:background="@color/lightbackground"`, because you no drawable defined for `color`.

Instead of it, you should use.

```
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way  id should be  android:id="@+id/text"

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/left" 
            android:background="@color/navy"
             android:layout_width="10.0dip" 
             android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/header" 
             android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bottom" 
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <TextView android:id="@id/right" 
            android:background="@color/lime"
             android:layout_width="10.0dip" 
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_alignTop="@id/header" 
              android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bottom" 
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:id="@+id/header" 
            android:background="@color/gray" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left">
            <TextView android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:textColor="#ff111111" 
                android:ellipsize="marquee" 
                android:gravity="center_vertical" 
                android:id="@+id/name" 
                android:paddingLeft="5.0dip" 
                android:paddingRight="5.0dip" 
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:singleLine="true" />

            <TextView android:textSize="12.0dip" 
              android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:textColor="#ff666666" 
                android:gravity="center_vertical" 
                android:id="@+id/date" 
                android:paddingRight="5.0dip" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                 android:singleLine="true" 
                 android:layout_weight="1.0" />
            <TextView android:textSize="14.0dip" 
                android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:textColor="@color/black" 
                 android:id="@+id/likes" android:paddingRight="5.0dip"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                   android:text=""
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            <RatingBar android:id="@+id/rate" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip" 
                android:max="5" 

                android:numStars="5"
                 android:stepSize="0.1" 
                android:isIndicator="true" 
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:textColor="#ff111111"
             android:id="@+id/body" 
             android:paddingLeft="5.0dip" 
             android:paddingTop="2.0dip" 
             android:paddingRight="5.0dip" 
             android:paddingBottom="5.0dip"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right" 
              android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left" 
              android:layout_below="@id/header" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/bottom"
             android:background="@color/teal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="10.0dip" 
              android:layout_below="@+id/body" 
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And @color in value/color

color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="green">#008000</color>
 <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

and open with

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `@id/` use `@+id/` . Try my below code your layout will be visible to you in graphical view.

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/left"
>     android:layout_width="10.0dip"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bottom"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/header"
>     android:background="@+color/lightbackground" />
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/right"
>     android:layout_width="10.0dip"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bottom"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/header"
>     android:background="@+color/lightbackground" />
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/header"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left"
>     android:background="@+color/gray_review_header"
>     android:gravity="center_vertical" >
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/name"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:ellipsize="marquee"
>         android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
>         android:gravity="center_vertical"
>         android:paddingLeft="5.0dip"
>         android:paddingRight="5.0dip"
>         android:singleLine="true"
>         android:textColor="#ff111111"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/date"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_weight="1.0"
>         android:gravity="center_vertical"
>         android:paddingRight="5.0dip"
>         android:singleLine="true"
>         android:textColor="#ff666666"
>         android:textSize="12.0dip"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/likes"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:paddingRight="5.0dip"
>         android:singleLine="true"
>         android:text=""
>         android:textColor="@+color/black"
>         android:textSize="14.0dip"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
>     <RatingBar
>         android:id="@+id/rate"
>         style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
>         android:isIndicator="true"
>         android:max="5"
>         android:numStars="5"
>         android:progressDrawable="@+drawable/ratebar_theme"
>         android:stepSize="0.1" />
> </LinearLayout>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/body"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/header"
>     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left"
>     android:paddingBottom="5.0dip"
>     android:paddingLeft="5.0dip"
>     android:paddingRight="5.0dip"
>     android:paddingTop="2.0dip"
>     android:textColor="#ff111111" />
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/bottom"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="10.0dip"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/body"
>     android:background="@+color/lightbackground" />
> ```

For your `@+color/` you need to define your colors in your `colors.xml` file as below:

> ```
>   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>     <resources>
>        <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
>        <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
>        <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
>        <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
>        <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
>        <color name="gray">#808080</color>
>        <color name="olive">#808000</color>
>        <color name="purple">#800080</color>
>        <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
>        <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
>        <color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
>        <color name="teal">#008080</color>
>        <color name="green">#008000</color>
>        <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
>        <color name="navy">#000080</color>
>        <color name="black">#000000</color>
>  </resources>
> ```

Comment: **@+** should only be used with **id** attribute. It is not meant for **color** drawable. color drawable can be accessed using **@android:color/..** or **@color**.